# Get Singleton behavior on WebJobs with custom queue processors

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues, azure-webjobs-triggered

My team has been trying to get some of our WebJobs [custom queue processors](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/CustomQueueProcessorFactory.cs) to have Singleton behavior, but we haven't really gotten that behavior with the `[Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]` attribute, nor with setting `QueueProcessorFactoryContext.BatchSize = 1`. This is causing nightly processes to slam the database all at once — with many of them timing out — and has become a bit of a headache.

This is more or less what our CustomQueueProcessorFactory looks like:

```
    public class CustomQueueProcessorFactory : IQueueProcessorFactory
    {
        public QueueProcessor Create(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

            if (context.Queue.Name == Constants.UploadQueueName 
                || context.Queue.Name == Constants.BuildQueueName)
            {
                context.BatchSize = 1;
            }

            return new QueueProcessor(context);
        }
    }
```

This is referenced when configuring our JobHost:

```
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    config.Queues.QueueProcessorFactory = new CustomQueueProcessorFactory();
```

We have also set up some functions with `QueueTrigger`s like:

```
    public static async Task ExecuteBackgroundRequest([QueueTrigger(Constants.BackgroundQueueName)] BackgroundRequest background, TextWriter logger)
    {
        await ExecuteRequest(background, logger);
    }

    [Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
    public static async Task ExecuteUploadRequest([QueueTrigger(Constants.UploadQueueName)] BackgroundRequest background, TextWriter logger)
    {
        await ExecuteRequest(background, logger);
    }

    [Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
    public static async Task ExecuteBuildRequest([QueueTrigger(Constants.BuildQueueName)] BackgroundRequest background, TextWriter logger)
    {
        await ExecuteRequest(background, logger);
    }
```

We are using the packages `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` (+ `.Core`, `.Extensions`) v2.0.0 and `WindowsAzure.Storage` v8.0.0, which are somewhat dated, so one potential solution I've been exploring is an update to the latest stable version of WebJobs (v3.0.4). This has opened a whole new can of worms, since the configuration has been completely redone, and all the classes have been moved around. The documentation seems sparse/scattered, so I have yet to determine where (or even if) I can customize properties on a per-QueueProcessor basis, like setting BatchSize to 1 for some queues while higher for others.

Is there some version of WebJobs where I can use the aforementioned CustomQueueProcessorFactory logic to limit BatchSize? Or where the Singleton attribute will actually ensure that only one background process is accessing a specific queue at a time? Can QueueProcessorFactories be configured in the most recent version of WebJobs?

Help on any of these questions would be appreciated immensely!

Answer (score 2):

The WebJobs SDK facilitates common distributed locking scenarios via its SingletonAttribute. You can simply apply SingletonAttribute to a job function to ensure that all invocations of that function will be serialized, even across scaled out instances. This is useful if your function needs to access other distributed resources or perform other operations that should not/cannot be performed concurrently.

```js
[Singleton]
public static async Task ProcessImage([BlobTrigger("images")] Stream image)
{
     // Process the image
}
```

Like in this example, only a single instance of the ProcessImage function will run at any given time. When the function is triggered by a new image being added to the images container, the runtime will first attempt to acquire the lock (blob lease). Once acquired, the lock is held (and the blob lease is renewed) for the duration of the function execution, ensuring no other instances will run. If another function instance is triggered while this function is running it will wait for the lock, periodically polling for it.

Singleton uses [Azure Blob Leases](http://justazure.com/azure-blob-storage-part-8-blob-leases/) under the covers to implement distributed locking. All of the complexities of managing the blob leases, lease renewals, etc. are handled by the SDK.

Singleton lock details are also shown in the WebJobs Dashboard, including the current lock status for an in progress function execution, as well as how long the function waited for the lock before acquiring it. You can use these details to view and manage lock contention.

[image]

Not concurrency scenarios will require use of Singleton. Some triggers have inherent support for concurrency management via their configuration settings. In such cases it will likely be more efficient for you to use the inbuilt support. You can use those settings to ensure that your function runs singleton on a single instance. To ensure only a single instance of the function is running across scaled out instances, in addition you can apply a listener level Singleton lock on the function (e.g. [Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]). The configuration knobs for some of the triggers are:

**QueueTrigger** - You can set JobHostConfiguration.Queues.BatchSize to 1
**ServiceBusTrigger** - You can set ServiceBusConfiguration.MessageOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls to 1
**FileTrigger** - You can set FileProcessor.MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 1
However, for triggers that don't support concurrency control inherently, or if you want to do more advanced locking via Singleton scopes (see below), Singleton is the right way to go.

Also i would say that implement your CustomQueueProcessorFactory  like below using double lock :-

```js
 if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock (SyncObject)
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                        {
                            _instance = new CustomQueueProcessor();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
```

Comment: does this => Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener) really ensure singleton support across scaled out instances?  Do you also need to ensure that the trigger type has the batch size set to 1?  Or is that an alternative method?  I don't think the batch size works across scaled out instances.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you want to multiple functions to process their triggering messages sequentially even after scaling-out. Am I right?

I think you can enforce this using the SingletonAttribute with [scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#singletonscopehost) parameters:

```
public static async Task ExecuteBackgroundRequest([QueueTrigger(Constants.BackgroundQueueName)] BackgroundRequest background, TextWriter logger)
{
    await ExecuteRequest(background, logger);
}

[Singleton("DatabaseSync", SingletonScope.Host)]
public static async Task ExecuteUploadRequest([QueueTrigger(Constants.UploadQueueName)] BackgroundRequest background, TextWriter logger)
{
    await ExecuteRequest(background, logger);
}

[Singleton("DatabaseSync", SingletonScope.Host)]
public static async Task ExecuteBuildRequest(
    [QueueTrigger(Constants.BuildQueueName)] BackgroundRequest background, TextWriter logger)
{
    await ExecuteRequest(background, logger);
}
```

Comment: What is `DatabaseSync` here?

Comment: `DatabaseSync` is the name of the scope ID that's the same across all functions that you don't want to run simultaneously.